# Automate the mysql secure installation using shell script

Tags: bash, scripts, expect

I am trying to automate mysql secure installation using linux shell scriping. I have below code got from https://gist.github.com/Mins/4602864.

```
#!/bin/bash

  MYSQL=$(grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log | awk '{print $11}')
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="test@123"

  SECURE_MYSQL=$(expect -c "

  set timeout 10
  spawn mysql_secure_installation

  expect "Enter password for user root:"
  send "$MYSQL\r"

  expect "Change the password for root ? ((Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) :"
  send "y\r"

  expect "New password:"
  send "$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD\r"

  expect "Re-enter new password:"
  send "$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD\r"

  expect "Do you wish to continue with the password provided?(Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) :"
  send "y\r"

  expect "Remove anonymous users? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) :"
  send "y\r"

  expect "Disallow root login remotely? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) :"
  send "y\r"

  expect "Remove test database and access to it? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) :"
  send "y\r"

  expect "Reload privilege tables now? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) :"
  send "y\r"

  expect eof
  "))

  echo "$SECURE_MYSQL"
```

But i am getting error

```
./sql.sh: command substitution: line 48: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./sql.sh: command substitution: line 48: `      expect "Change the password for root ? ((Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) :"'
```

I have tried to figure out the error but no success.

Answer (score 1):

Try this as it is, seems like there is a some issue with `(` and pipe `|` so I had to escape them.

#### Source Code

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

      MYSQL=$(grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log | awk '{print $11}')
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="test@123"

      SECURE_MYSQL=$(expect -c "

      set timeout 10
      spawn mysql_secure_installation

      expect "Enter password for user root:"
      send "$MYSQL\r"

      expect "Change the password for root ?\(Press y\|Y for Yes, any other key for No\) :"
      send "y\r"

      expect "New password:"
      send "$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD\r"

      expect "Re-enter new password:"
      send "$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD\r"

      expect "Do you wish to continue with the password provided?\(Press y\|Y for Yes, any other key for No\) :"
      send "y\r"

      expect "Remove anonymous users?\(Press y\|Y for Yes, any other key for No\) :"
      send "y\r"

      expect "Disallow root login remotely?\(Press y\|Y for Yes, any other key for No\) :"
      send "y\r"

      expect "Remove test database and access to it?\(Press y\|Y for Yes, any other key for No\) :"
      send "y\r"

      expect "Reload privilege tables now?\(Press y\|Y for Yes, any other key for No\) :"
      send "y\r"

      expect eof
      ")

      echo "$SECURE_MYSQL"
```

Debug execution

```
root@5015a2757ac4:/# bash -x secure.sh
++ grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log
++ awk '{print $11}'
grep: /var/log/mysqld.log: No such file or directory
+ MYSQL=
+ MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test@123
++ expect -c '

      set timeout 10
      spawn mysql_secure_installation

      expect Enter' password for user 'root:
      send r

      expect Change' the password for root '?(Press' 'y|Y' for Yes, any other key for 'No)' ':
      send yr

      expect New' 'password:
      send test@123r

      expect Re-enter' new 'password:
      send test@123r

      expect Do' you wish to continue with the password 'provided?(Press' 'y|Y' for Yes, any other key for 'No)' ':
      send yr

      expect Remove' anonymous 'users?(Press' 'y|Y' for Yes, any other key for 'No)' ':
      send yr

      expect Disallow' root login 'remotely?(Press' 'y|Y' for Yes, any other key for 'No)' ':
      send yr

      expect Remove' test database and access to 'it?(Press' 'y|Y' for Yes, any other key for 'No)' ':
      send yr

      expect Reload' privilege tables 'now?(Press' 'y|Y' for Yes, any other key for 'No)' ':
      send yr

      expect eof
      '

couldn't read file "password": no such file or directory
+ SECURE_MYSQL='spawn mysql_secure_installation

Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Connecting to MySQL using a blank password.

VALIDATE PASSWORD PLUGIN can be used to test passwords
and improve security. It checks the strength of password
and allows the users to set only those passwords which are
secure enough. Would you like to setup VALIDATE PASSWORD plugin?

Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No: '
+ echo 'spawn mysql_secure_installation

Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Connecting to MySQL using a blank password.

VALIDATE PASSWORD PLUGIN can be used to test passwords
and improve security. It checks the strength of password
and allows the users to set only those passwords which are
secure enough. Would you like to setup VALIDATE PASSWORD plugin?

Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No: '
spawn mysql_secure_installation

Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Connecting to MySQL using a blank password.

VALIDATE PASSWORD PLUGIN can be used to test passwords
and improve security. It checks the strength of password
and allows the users to set only those passwords which are
secure enough. Would you like to setup VALIDATE PASSWORD plugin?

Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No:
root@5015a2757ac4:/#
```

And I have verified the login with new password `test@123`.

Comment: I am getting error `./secure.sh: line 39: expect: command not found`

Comment: @Janith, that means you have not installed `expect` command. try `apt-get install expect -y` and try again.

Comment: thank you for your support. Still getting the error `couldn't read file "password": no such file or directory
spawn mysql_secure_installation

Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root:`

Comment: @Janith, Are you sure that you exactly executing as given ? cause Its worked for me.

Comment: Yes I copied exact script which you are given

Comment: Also doesn't work for me, it still asks for the password. It's like the expect just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Below script worked for me.

```
#!/bin/bash

  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='Password@123'
  MYSQL=$(grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log | awk '{print $11}')

  SECURE_MYSQL=$(expect -c "

  set timeout 10
  spawn mysql_secure_installation

  expect \"Enter password for user root:\"
  send \"$MYSQL\r\"
  expect \"New password:\"
  send \"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD\r\"
  expect \"Re-enter new password:\"
  send \"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD\r\"
  expect \"Change the password for root ?\ ((Press y\|Y for Yes, any other key for No) :\"
  send \"y\r\"
  send \"$MYSQL\r\"
  expect \"New password:\"
  send \"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD\r\"
  expect \"Re-enter new password:\"
  send \"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD\r\"
  expect \"Do you wish to continue with the password provided?\(Press y\|Y for Yes, any other key for No) :\"
  send \"y\r\"
  expect \"Remove anonymous users?\(Press y\|Y for Yes, any other key for No) :\"
  send \"y\r\"
  expect \"Disallow root login remotely?\(Press y\|Y for Yes, any other key for No) :\"
  send \"n\r\"
  expect \"Remove test database and access to it?\(Press y\|Y for Yes, any other key for No) :\"
  send \"y\r\"
  expect \"Reload privilege tables now?\(Press y\|Y for Yes, any other key for No) :\"
  send \"y\r\"
  expect eof
  ")

  echo $SECURE_MYSQL
```

Comment: What does the awk print $11 do

Comment: When I try running I get `grep: /var/log/mysqld.log: No such file or directory` in CentOS 8.1 and mariadb because that is so. I know this is askUbuntu tho but still why $11